# Ionic 1 project to build IOS app and try to upload it appstore

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, xcode9

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W01UE.png)

When I am trying to run ionic project on simulator it works fine, but get the IPA file from archive through this error please help me. I am hopeless.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1814/_index.html

Comment: Please follow this link you have to create  provisioning-profile for that you have to do this thing steps by steps https://learn.adafruit.com/introduction-to-ios-development/create-a-distribution-provisioning-profile

Answer (score 0):

You can not create an archived IPA when an iOS simulator is selected. You must plug in your own real iOS device and select it in Xcode.

Your iPhone/iPad will then ask if you want to trust this computer. Select yes, and then Xcode will create a provisioning profile for that device. This provisioning profile will be saved in your Apple Developer Account and can be viewed in iTunes Connect.

After the provisioning process has completed, you should be able to successfully archive your app.

I hope this helps, and good luck!